# Jquery Select Menu Option Fails if page is refreshed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select menu with two options, yes or no. If the user selects yes, the class 'hidden' is remove from the table which then shows the table. If no, the table is hidden.

If i refresh the webpage, the select menu stays on the previous selection and the code doesnt fire until i select the option again.

How can i fix this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#checkrequestyesorno').click(function () {
        if( $('#checkrequestyesorno').val() == "Yes") {
            $("#checkrequesttable").removeClass('hidden');
        }else{
            $("#checkrequesttable").addClass('hidden');
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Add a default setting to the drop down.  <option selected....  >No</option>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You you can fix this issue by using two scenarios.

**Scenario 1,** by adding class by default to your HTML element and selecting your required option by default:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="checkrequesttable" class="hidden">...</div>
<select id="checkrequestyesorno">
    <option value="no" selected>No</option>
    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
</select>
```

**Scenario 2,** by selecting your required option by default and writing your JQuery Functionality in some custom function. Then you will need to call your custom function in both situaitons e.i. [Document On ready](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=ready) and Select box [click](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=click):

**HTML:**

```
<select id="checkrequestyesorno">
    <option value="no" selected>No</option>
    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript/JQuery:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    checkRequestFunc();
    $('#checkrequestyesorno').click(function () {
        checkRequestFunc();
    });
});

function checkRequestFunc(){

   if( $('#checkrequestyesorno').val() == "Yes") {
      $("#checkrequesttable").removeClass('hidden');
   }else{
      $("#checkrequesttable").addClass('hidden');
   }

}
```

> By the way, when you are dealing with a `HTML Element Select` using [JQuery Method .change()](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=change) is a good approach, so if you  are willing to use this you can write your code like below:

**HTML:**

```
<select id="checkrequestyesorno">
    <option value="no" selected>No</option>
    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript/JQuery:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    checkRequestFunc();
    $('#checkrequestyesorno').change(function() {
        checkRequestFunc();
    });
});

function checkRequestFunc(){

   if( $('#checkrequestyesorno').val() == "Yes") {
      $("#checkrequesttable").removeClass('hidden');
   }else{
      $("#checkrequesttable").addClass('hidden');
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Without any markup supplied, I believe you are trying to accomplish this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var checkYesOrNo = $('#checkrequestyesorno');
  var checkTable = $('#checkrequesttable');
  checkYesOrNo.change(function() {
    if (checkYesOrNo.val() === "Yes") {
      checkTable.removeClass('hidden');
    } else {
      checkTable.addClass('hidden');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Show table:</h3>
<select id="checkrequestyesorno">
  <option value="No" selected>No</option>
  <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
</select>

<table class="hidden" id="checkrequesttable">
  <tr>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>fooTable</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <td>bar</td>
    <td>baz</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

I took the liberty of storing your queries as variables. Remember that the DOM is *slow*, and you should avoid multiple DOM queries whenever possible. Also, listening for the `change` event will work better than `click` in this example, because the `value` of the `select` element does not change on `click`, but rather on `change`.